# Load external web page to my website section

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am trying to load external pages  display in my website.External pages are locally hosted on a server in same network. So i called those pages in iframe like below

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.11/DSS/DashboardEngine.aspx?DashboardID=Muda\PSI\Rainfall" scrolling="auto" runat="server" width="99.8%" height="455px"></iframe>
```

It is working if i access website from inside the network.But if access website from outside of network then that iframe section doesn't reach on local ip and giving error in iframe section.

*Is there any way to run that iframe section on server side and then display it on client side?*

If i access website locally then it display local pages in iframe without any error like below
[image]

If i access to website outside then that local pages in iframe giving error like un reachable to ip.here is error
[image]

Comment: You need to use the public ip address instead of local, or try using service like ngrok which will generate a public URL of your local hosted website that can be accessed from anywhere in the world.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh sir what is this service ngrok?

Comment: It Makes your local server pages accessible on the Web by any client. As currently you are  using the local ip address that is why you are not able to access the website in the frame if you are outside the network.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh thats what i need but again in my iframe src , that current link will be change?it would be some other link to access those pages?

Comment: Obviously, but I think you can change the link.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh link change is not an issue for me but do i need to download the app and intall on that local hosted server?

Comment: Isn't it already on local hosted server?

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh basically those pages are generated by an application adn locally hosted on same server. i need to show those pages in a section of my website.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh i attached snapshot for accessing website within network and outside network.please chk that

Comment: Type what is my ip in Google and copy the ip it    shows and then access the URL in iframe replace the starting ip with the ip you just copied. See if you can access it?

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh i need that ip search from google and do i need install ngrok also with that?

Comment: No you don't need ngrok with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77994/discussion-between-vimalsingh-and-mbaljeetsingh).

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh 
ohh great but with that public ip can i access local hosted website form anyother systtem?

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh i think local hosted website can not access with a public ip
should i open any port then i can access?

Comment: That is where ngrok comes in to play

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh i just tried ngrok on my laptop.and try to access local hosted web on my laptop.its really working fine but only one confusion.is it safe to use ngrok?

Comment: I think it is good for testing purposes, but for production I would suggest you choose something like digital ocean

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh digital ocean is safe to install on server?and for use of website.our main website is already hosted on web but that other web server is locally hosted, i use only two pages of that web server in my main website.

Answer (score 0):

With iFrame, it does not load the data ever to the host server. iFrame is ran on the clients device and loads inside of it.

To do something similar to showing a website's content inside your own, you would have to on call to a page, download the other pages content (html, hopefully all static with no dynamic or server calls) and inject it into your page.

That is to say, that just because you can see the internal server, does not mean the client can. So you would have to proxy the content.

Comment: pages are not fully static .few filters are there for filter data

Comment: You could proxy through the website, but it brings into question why you would ever need to do this. If it is just the data you need, then someone should expose an API to get to this data.

Comment: @ Zach S. how do i do proxy through the website?basically those web pages from another server generated by an application and hosted locally on that server.i need to show those pages in our website?